# testing the alignment of button with corresponding text with nightwatchjs

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

I am using nightwatchjs for automation.i need to automate lists of sellers and the corresponding button.

for eg : I have a list of sellers name in my add to cart and each seller has a add to cart button.
walmart.com  addtocart
target.com   addtocart
circuitcity  addtocart

I inially thought of counting the number of addtocart button and then equating with the number of sellers.But it will not test the alignment of the button.The test case should be the each seller name has the corresponding add to cart.
the html code for the ul class for the seller name and button is given below:

```
<ul class="js-marketplace-sellers-list">
<li class="js-marketplace-seller js-seller-closable selected" data-seller-id="132" data-automation-id="product-mp-seller-132">
<li class="js-marketplace-seller" data-seller-id="51" data-automation-id="product-mp-seller-51">
<li class="js-marketplace-seller js-seller-closable" data-seller-id="0" data-automation-id="product-mp-seller-0">
<li class="js-marketplace-seller js-seller-closable" data-seller-id="130" data-automation-id="product-mp-seller-130">
<li class="js-marketplace-seller js-seller-closable" data-seller-id="111" data-automation-id="product-mp-seller-111">
<li class="js-marketplace-seller js-seller-closable" data-seller-id="17" data-automation-id="product-mp-seller-17">
</ul>
```

what can be the approach to test the alignment of the addtocartbutton along with the seller and to see each seller has one button.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by testing the alignment.

Comment: so that each seller has one addtocart button by its side. eg.  walmart  addtocart............target   addtocart